# Linux SECURE WEB FILES:preferred file privileges for web files/directories

Tags: linux, security, file-permissions, directory-permissions

What web (what for html, shtml, css, js, pl, py, php and what for included php files) file permission is the highest security permission I can give to the above files (where 755, where 644) and what to directories(in localhost e.g.:www,www/css, 
home/gregor/.silly/.idonotwanttonamethatdirpasswordsbutthatsit)?

Can I remove -x to 600 privileges on subdir .silly? I know I must not do that on www or www/css and I suppose I can NOT also remove -x to 600 on subsubdir .idonotwanttonamethatdirpasswordsbutthatsit?

Is there a difference if a php file IS ONLY INCLUDED in another file and not called anytime directly? Can I set privileges in such files to -x 644 or must it be 755 too?

Is it more secure to put .passwords in out of web dir I mean localhost path in one hidden sub dir or is it the same if I put it in 
localhost/.ha/.whateversubdirpassword?

What privileges does the system look up for to check if it can display/execute file when smbd from another computer accesses via net the index.php or index.html? (And does it matter if server needs to process file? I mean .php ...) Or to put it so in which group does that user belong - do anonymous users have group id, lets say "1111"?
Thanks, Gregor from Slovenia

Comment: I think that you are asking how to secure your web server. Which web server are you using?

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04 LTS with Apache/PHP/MySQL

Comment: You should google `lamp file permissions`. There are many explanations